# HTML-PHP Form, Need Advice

Tags: php, html, forms, function

I am making a program that will accept user input and then check to see if the input is a valid ISBN10.

I have made a basic HTML form and a function in PHP to check for ISBN validation. I haven't started any of the input validation yet but every time I input data and submit it I end up with a blank form again and not my messages declaring if the input is a valid ISBN or not.

I would appreciate if you could check over my code to see if there is anything glaringly obvious that I am/am not doing.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<?php

if (isset ($_POST['isbn']))

{

    $isbn = $_POST['isbn'];


function validate_isbn($isbn) 

{

if (strlen != 10) 

{
    return false;

    echo "Please enter a ten-digit ISBN.";
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) 

{
    $check = $check + (10 - $i) * substr ($i, 1);
}

$check = $check % 11;

if (empty ( $check )) 

{
    return true;

    echo $_POST ["isbn"], " is a VALID ten-digit ISBN.";
} 

else 

{
    return false;

    echo $_POST ["isbn"], " is NOT A VALID ten-digit ISBN.";
}
}

}

?>
```

```
<form action ="isbnvalid.php" method = "POST">

    This program will validate an ISBN:

    <br>
    <br>


    Please input a ten digit ISBN: <input type="number" name="isbn" size=12> 

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Validate">

</form>
```

Comment: We are *not* debuggers. You need **isolate any problems** and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a **clear explanation of what isn't working** with a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Thing is, "how" are you calling this function `validate_isbn()`? That's not included in your code.

Comment: Then you're using returns, and echos under those. Once the returns kick in, the echos won't do anything.

Comment: sorry but your question is just way too unclear for *moi*. Best you debug your code.

Comment: @JohnConde I'm new to all this and still learning, basically teaching myself bit by bit, I know you aren't here to debug my code but I thought it was a place were people help each other out. I have done research and am putting in bits of code from here and there but as you can see I haven't quite got it yet.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I can't make it much clearer I'm afraid. I'll get rid of the returns to see if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think you need this kind of work

```
if (isset ($_REQUEST['submit']))

{

    $isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
    if($isbn == "") {
         echo $msg = '<span class="error"> Please fill all the values</span>';
    }else if(!is_numeric($isbn)) {
        echo $msg = '<span class="error"> Data entered was not numeric</span>';
    }else if(strlen($isbn) <= 10) {
        echo $msg = '<span class="error"> The number entered was not 10 digits long</span>';
    } else {
        /* Success */
        //echo "success";
    }




}

?>
<form action="" method="post">

    This program will validate an ISBN:

    <br>
    <br>


    Please input a ten digit ISBN: <input type="text" name="isbn"> 

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Validate">

</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the input, I see what I was donig wrong now, this pointed me in the right direction, finally got it working. Next I am going to figure out how to only show one of the messages after I hit the Validate button.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling your function `validate_isbn($isbn)` you have to call it.

```
$isbn = $_POST['isbn'];

if(validate_isbn($isbn)) {
    echo "ISBN is valid!";
}
```

And also remember:

> `return` returns program control to the calling module. Execution
>   resumes at the expression following the called module's invocation.

This means your function doesn't ouput something because you return something in before.

Comment: Thanks for the help, no point making the function if I don't actually call it :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the echo BEFORE the return - if there is an return, nothing after it will be touched...